# Parallax 'background-image/position/attachment' jQuery animation is jittery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, parallax

Here's the breakdown...

- wrapper (position:relative; overflow:hidden; )

  - section-container (position:absolute)

    - multiple child sections

I attach a mousewheel event listener and animate (with easing) the 'top' position of 'section-container'. As this position changes, the 'background-position' of each section moves vertically based on the position of 'section-container's 'top' property (continually updated through a setTimeout()).

All of that works as it should, except as the 'background-position' changes, the image has a bit of a jitter. This doesn't happen if the 'background-attachment' is set to 'fixed'... but I don't want that.

Can anyone explain this, with a possible fix? I continually refer to the https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/ site and can't figure out what they're doing differently to get theirs operating so efficiently.

Comment: landrover site is developed by a really powerfull team Paul Cheteles and George Cheteles. Its really complicated website to understand fully. site javascript = https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/js/LandRoverSite.js

Comment: Ehh... not really. I'm using a combination of a tweaked 'superscrollorama/TweenMax/TimelineLite' ... a tweaked 'iscroll' (that uses 'top', instead of 'translate3d'). I'm getting the right effect now since I changed the way I was updating the 'top' property.

Comment: That's not to say it wasn't written well, though. I'd only critique that Page Up/Down doesn't do anything on their site.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out, i believe its where they do most of the animating:
https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/js/ScrollAnimator.js?v=471

I would have to say they have some kind of framework that they are using to accomplish this.

EDIT: Sorry didn't see the new answer above mine, seems like a good starting point.

-Ken

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect [this website](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/) carefully, you will able to use it like landrover site.

You need to use: [scrollTo plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) and [parallax plugin](http://www.ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/scripts/jquery.parallax-1.1.3.js)

And document jQuery should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav').localScroll(800);

    //.parallax(xPosition, speedFactor, outerHeight) options:
    //xPosition - Horizontal position of the element
    //inertia - speed to move relative to vertical scroll. Example: 0.1 is one tenth the speed of scrolling, 2 is twice the speed of scrolling
    //outerHeight (true/false) - Whether or not jQuery should use it's outerHeight option to determine when a section is in the viewport
    $('#intro').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('#second').parallax("50%", 0.1);
    $('.bg').parallax("50%", 0.4);
    $('#third').parallax("50%", 0.3);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So I figured out my issue was when trying to animate() the 'section-container' on the 'top' property. I was using a "+=" to allow it to increment from its current position. Not a good idea when using 'mousewheel' events. I changed it to a hard-set variable that is continually incremented/decremented.